# Как написать запрос к db.mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Опишу в кратце:

Например есть 2 таблицы админы и статьи

мне нужно выташить одним запросом по критерию `article_id` имя и `id`, `realname` из админ таблицы и все остальное из таблицы статей, при этом запросе должна быть проверка в таблице cтатьи у `author id`, чтобы случайно не вытащить чужую статью.

запрос примерно вот такой упростил дальше некуда.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT dba.id, dbb.id,dbb.realname
                                FROM cms_articles AS dba 
                                INNER JOIN cms_admins AS dbb 
                                ON dba.author_id=dbb.id 
                                WHERE dba.id='".$articles["article_id"]."' AND dba.author_id='".USER_ID."'");
```

Параметры которые вводятся `$articles["article_id"]` показывает 1 и USER_ID показывает 1 у статьи в базе которую надо ввывести `author_id` 1 и `id` тоже показывает 1 но почему то возвращается `false` постоянно.

Comment: false означает, что в запросе ошибка. Надо смотреть какая: mysql_query("select ...") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: да вроде прошла. а как определить id статьи и id пользователя их надо менять имена?

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: т.е вместо mysql_query например использовать функции mysqli???

Comment: всесто расширения mysql сообществом php настоятельно рекомендуется использовать расширение mysqli или PDO

Comment: понял, хотелось начать пользоваться, а подумал, что это примочка не на всех серверах есть. она теперь постовляется не расширение для php, а используется в самом php ?

Comment: это всё расширения, и mysql и mysqli и pdo, просто они разрабатываются в том же потоке, что и ядро php.

Comment: @eicto, я однажды затронул тему по поводу древнего mysql, и вы сказали, что люди стали стараться переходить на mysqli хотя бы. Однако, по однотипным вопросам я вижу, что человеки продолжают учиться по литературе 2005 года. Включительно. ((( Увы...

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил.

Вся загвостка в том,что запрос не поддерживает вот такие кавычки `dba.article_id` вместо этого нужно писать dba.article_id

Comment: В прямых кавычках пишутся строковые значения, в косых названия таблиц и полей (и др.)

Answer (score 0):

false возвращается потому, что у вас значения типа INT заключены в одинарные ковычки, а по правилам синтаксиса SQL они должны подставляться как есть. Пример:

```
dba.id = 1, (а не dba.id = '1')
```

Comment: Бред. Числовые значения можно в кавычки заключать. И для защиты от инъекций полезно.

Comment: пока писал вы уже ответили сами себе, правда вы не правы насчет этих кавычек, просто вы их не правильно применяете. Надо так:

    `dba`.`article_id` а не `dba.article_id`

Но применять их вовсе не обязательно, если только вы не используете в именах столбцов спецсимволы и зарезервированные слова, что само по себе плохая практика

Comment: @Алексей Мотылёв,
а) принимать такое - исключительно добрая воля БД  
б) не уверен, что это автоматически скастуется во всех командах  
в) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781976/mysql-quote-numbers-or-not - смотрим комментарии, в т.ч. про индексы
г) "И для защиты от инъекций полезно." - у меня просто нет слов, в int/float скастовать уже не модно? А если там как раз-таки строка с кавычкой, которая закроет вашу строка, а дальше идет инъекция?

Comment: @Алексей Мотылёв да насчет ошибки погорячился, но все-таки правильно будет числа писать без ковычек, так как если вы их заключаете в ковычки, то передаете их БД в виде строки, заставляя ее тем самым делать преобразование типов, что очень не значительно (ничтожно), но увеличивает время выполнения запроса. Но а против иньекций давно придумано real_escape_string()

Comment: у меня так и было `dba`.`article_id` и именно из-за этого и выдавал денвер ошибку unknown column `dba`.`article_id`

Comment: Без кавычек, конечно, правильнее, но я имел ввиду, что это врядли может вызвать ошибку. От инъекций это не может защитить, но может спасти в некоторых ситуациях (если кавычки экранируются). Но лучше всего поможет использование placeholder или prepare.